# Trouble finding R in a super mesh

Tags: resistors, circuit-analysis

[image: Finding R in this circuit]

I am trying to find \$R\$ in \$R_5\$ via mesh analysis. I see that loops 1 and 2 are a super mesh, so then applying KVL to them I end up with:

$$
4\cdot(i_1-i_2) + R\cdot(i_2-i_3) + 2\cdot i_1 + 5\cdot i_2 = 0
$$

It is clear that the current in mesh 3 is -1. In the super mesh \$i_1\$ and \$i_2\$, the current is \$i_1 - i_2 = 6\$.

after plugging in my values I am left with the following:

$$
36 + 7\cdot i_2 + R\cdot i_2 + R = 0
$$

How am I supposed to solve for \$R\$ from here? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: We apply super mesh when there is current source in the network. Typical method is to remove the current source to get the bigger mesh (super mesh). I don’t see that here. As a side note, this problem is better suited for nodal analysis.

Comment: How are mesh 1 and 2 not a super mesh?

Comment: The circuit you have given is the main circuit but how does it look after removing the current sources?

Comment: But they share a common current source.

Comment: You can go the supermesh route...I think there is a way to "cheat" by assigning a variable to the voltage drop across the current source(make peoples head explode) :)

Answer (score 2):

Lots of bad advice on this page, so I'm going to answer this even after all this time.

First, you don't have any supermeshes. By definition a supermesh is closed path that does not include a current source on its edges. There are no such paths here.

Furthermore, by inspection I2 = -2A and I3 = -1A. So the current through R5 (going up) is 1A. Also, by KCL, I1 + 2A = 6A. So I1 = 4A.

To find the voltage drop across R5 you need to find two paths form a ref node to both ends of R5 such that these paths pass only through resistors other than R5 (i.e. these paths cannot pass through R5 or any current sources). No two such paths exist. Which means the value of R in this circuit is not fixed/determined by rest of the components (including the current sources).

To convince yourself, assign some arbitrary value to R5 and solve the circuit, say in a simulator to save time. And then try to assign some other value to R5. The circuit is still solvable, you'll just get another voltage drop across R5.

[image]
[image]

You can even try it yourself [here](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$+1+0.000005+0.038353157287631064+43+5+43%0Ai+384+384+384+464+0+2%0Ai+480+384+400+384+0+6%0Ar+416+464+496+464+0+5%0Ar+496+384+496+464+0+1%0Ar+496+464+576+464+0+6%0Ar+496+384+608+384+0+4%0Ar+384+320+608+320+0+2%0Aw+384+320+384+384+2%0Aw+608+384+608+320+2%0Ai+608+384+608+464+0+-1%0Aw+416+464+384+464+2%0Aw+400+384+384+384+0%0Aw+480+384+496+384+2%0Ag+496+464+496+496+0%0Aw+576+464+608+464+2%0A).

Answer (score 0):

\$I_2\$ is clearly -2 A, so you can get \$R=29\$ assuming your equations are right.
What I cannot understand is how did you even get the KVL equations, because I couldn't find any loop without current source, and voltage across a current source is not defined.

If I am not incorrect, then the value of \$R\$ can be anything, and the circuit solution is independent of \$R\$. In fact, if you apply i-shift, repeatedly, you get it completely disjoint from the other components.